# Mock or initialise EditForm and EditContext with bUnit and C#

Tags: c#, blazor, bunit

I'm using Radzen for Blazor components and I have following form:

```
<EditForm @ref=@_editForm Model="@_selectedItem">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex">
            <RadzenDataGrid @ref=@_grid
                            IsLoading=@_isLoading
                            Count=@_totalItems
                            Data=@_items
                            ...
                            TItem="UserItem">
                <EmptyTemplate>
                    <p class="datagrid-no-records">No matching results</p>
                </EmptyTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="UserItem" Property="User.Email" Title="User Name" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left">
                        <Template Context="item">
                            <RadzenLabel Text=@item.User.Email MouseEnter="@item.OnEmailTooltipShow" MouseLeave="@item.OnTooltipHide"/>
                        </Template>
                        <EditTemplate Context="item">
                            <CascadingValue Value=@_editForm.EditContext IsFixed="false">
                                <div class="cell-item">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="item.User.Email" class="w-100 mb-1" @oninput="@item.OnEmailChange" />
                                    <ValidationMessage For="(() => item.User.Email)" />
                                </div>
                            </CascadingValue>
                        </EditTemplate>
                    </RadzenDataGridColumn>

                    ...
                </Columns>
            </RadzenDataGrid>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

and code behind:

```
private List<UserItem> _items = new();
private RadzenDataGrid<UserItem> _grid;
private UserDto _selectedItem = new();
private EditForm _editForm;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{    
     if (firstRender && _editForm?.EditContext != null)
     {
          _editForm.EditContext.OnFieldChanged -= EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
         _editForm.EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;     
     }
}
```

I want to write bUnit test to cover:

```
if (firstRender && _editForm?.EditContext != null)
{
          _editForm.EditContext.OnFieldChanged -= EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
         _editForm.EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;     
}
```

The unit test look like:

```
using var ctx = new TestContext();
...
var userManagementPage = ctx.RenderComponent<UserManagement>();
```

but that block is never reached because `_editForm` is always null, I don't know how to init the model and `EditContext` as well.

How to do that ?

Comment: Hey, can you show your complete code (including the test)?

The `EditContext` is most likely `null` because your model is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

//you can try below

```
userManagementPage.Instance._editForm = new Telerik.Blazor.Components.TelerikForm
        {
           EditContext = new EditContext(new yourModel())
        };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).